# Combine a list of data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a specific method for combining a list of data.tables in R?

I have a list of ~20 data.tables, each with around 1 million rows, and would like to combine them into one data.table with 20 million rows.

I've been doing it with

```
Reduce('rbind', data.table)
```

but it takes a while.

Tnx!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See `?rbindlist` and these related questions (easier to find when you know what to search for!) :

[data.table questions and answers containing `rbindlist`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bdata.table%5D%20rbindlist)

Comment: Didn't know you had incorporated a function specifically for this task. Nice work, and per usual - it is quite fast.

Answer (score 24):

Using `do.call` appears to be about 10x faster with this made up example:

```
library(data.table)

x1 <- data.table(x = runif(1e6), y = runif(1e6))
x2 <- data.table(x = runif(1e6), y = runif(1e6))

#20 data.tables all of length 1e6
yourList <- list(x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2)

system.time(out1 <- Reduce("rbind", yourList))
#-----
   user  system elapsed 
   3.37    3.03    6.43 
system.time(out2 <- do.call("rbind", yourList))
#-----
   user  system elapsed 
   0.33    0.36    0.68 
all.equal(out1,out2)
#-----
[1] TRUE
```

### Edit - to incorporate Matt's answer

I did not realize `data.table` had a specific function for this task. Par for the course, it is quite fast. Here is the relevant timing:

```
system.time(out3 <- rbindlist(yourList))
#-----
   user  system elapsed 
   0.07    0.03    0.11 

all.equal(out1,out3)
#-----
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

For my money, the plyr package's `ldply` is the by way to do this.  I has the advantage that the name of the list element is added as a new first column, named `.id`.

In addition, a list of data frames is often the output of `tapply`, in which case replace the whole shebang with `ddply`.

Alternatives include `do.call("rbind", mylist)` or lattice's `make.groups` (haven't been able to find this one recently though).

---

Note: I may have misunderstood the question-I read `data.frame` instead of `data.table`.  These techniques still work, but I'm not sure they result in a `data.table` all of the time.

Comment: OP has 20 * 1 million rows, though, and had speed issue to solve.

Comment: Fair point, data.table can but used to solve some awkward performance issues, although its wise to include the cost of keying the table, it's not clear if that's addressed here.

Comment: True but keying the table doesn't come into this particular question. In general, yes it would be nice to see more benchmarks split off and report the time to `setkey`. Typically that is done once, like in a database, but is still relevant. Unkeyed aggregation is pretty fast, so usually no need to key for that.