# How to read and rbind large CSV file efficiently?

Tags: r, csv

I have 20 large CSV (100-150MB each) files i would like to load in R and rbind them in a large file and perform my analysis. Reading each CSV file is performed on one core only and takes about 7 min. I am on 64bit 8-core linux with 16gb RAM so resources should not be an issue.

Is there any way to perform this process more efficiently? I am also open to other (open source linux) software (for example binding the CSV files in a different programm and loading in R) or anything that could make this process faster.

Thank you very much

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1820610/602276

Comment: Out of curiosity, what function(s) are you using that you are waiting 7 minutes?

Comment: Andrie's link helps with the reading .csv part, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12252047/403310 should help with the `rbind` part. You can use `rbindlist` on `data.frame` as well as `data.table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want a function like [`paste`](http://ss64.com/bash/paste.html). It's a bash function that merge lines of files.